# Pose of the object in Roboearth

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to determine the pose of the object that has been detected by Kinect using Roboearth.

I am not able to see the detected node giving me the pose of the object. I did run echo tf, but its giving me someinfo about Kinect and nothing abt the pose of the object.
How do we determine this ??
Can any one help me out.

Regards,
Faizan Mohammed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11475/pose-of-the-object-in-roboearth/) by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when you try to save the object's name you would give a class to the object and name to the object. Lets say when you were saying the object you gave the class as "box" and name as "red".

So your object's id is box.red and to get a pose of the object with respect to the kinect you should give the parent id and child id by using rosrun tf tf_echo parent_id child_id.

so here it will be: rosrun tf tf_echo openni_depth_camera box.red

and you will get the pose in terms of translation, quaternions and RPY.

Regards,
Faizan Mohammed

---

Originally posted by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) with karma: 71 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-08**:
Thanks for the answer!